# paintComponents method not being called in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

I watched a tutorial and tried to do same thing, I wrote the codes exactly the same but it shows nothing. I think it is because paintComponent method is not being called, I also tried to print something to console by paintComponent.

Here is my code:

```
public class Line extends JPanel{

    @Override
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(100, 10, 30, 40);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Line l =new Line();

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Line");
        myFrame.setSize(600, 400);        
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.add(l);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are awesome! thanks! @Berger

Comment: Yes sorry I removed the comment, `paintComponents` with a `s` exists, but what you want to override is `paintComponent` .

Comment: Is Berger a ninja, cos I cant see any comments or replies. :)

Comment: @SteveSmith now you can see :)

Comment: @Ms.Sahin instead of editing the title, post an answer showing how the problem was solved and accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to override is `paintComponent`, not `paintComponents` with a `s` .

`paintComponents` paints the child components of the current component (well it sort of tells the child components to paint themselves on the `Graphics` object).

`paintComponent` paints the component itself, this is the method you want to override to do custom painting for your component.